# Resource usage using pipe and here string

Tags: bash, pipe, resources

We can get the same result using the following two in `bash`,

```
echo 'foo' | cat
```

and

```
cat <<< 'foo'
```

My question is what are the difference between these two as far as the resources used are concerned and which one is better ?

My thought is that while using pipe we are using an extra process `echo` and pipe while in here string only a file descriptor is being used with `cat`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The pipe is a file opened in an in-kernel file-system and is not accessible as a regular file on-disk. It is automatically buffered only to a certain size and will eventually block when full. Unlike files sourced on block-devices, pipes behave very like character devices, and so generally do not support *`lseek()`* and data read from them cannot be read again as you might do with a regular file.

The here-string is a regular file created in a mounted file-system. The shell creates the file and retains its descriptor while immediately removing its only file-system link *(and so deleting it)* before ever it writes/reads a byte to/from the file. The kernel will maintain the space required for the file until all processes release all descriptors for it. If the child reading from such a descriptor has the capability to do so, it can be rewound with *`lseek()`* and read again.

In both cases the tokens `<<<` and `|` represent file-descriptors and not necessarily the files themselves. You can get a better idea of what's going on by doing stuff like:

```
readlink /dev/fd/1 | cat
```

...or...

```
ls -l <<<'' /dev/fd/*
```

The most significant difference between the two files is that the here-string/doc is pretty much an all-at-once affair - the shell writes all data into it before offering the read descriptor up to the child. On the other hand, the shell opens the pipe on the appropriate descriptors and forks off children to manage those for the pipe - and so it is written/read *concurrently* at both ends.

These distinctions, though, are only *generally* true. As far as I am aware *(which isn't really all that far)* this is true of pretty much every shell which handles the `<<<` here-string short-hand for `<<` a here-document redirection with the single exception of [`yash`](http://yash.osdn.jp/index.html.en). `yash`, `busybox`, `dash`, and other `ash` variants do tend to back here-documents with pipes, though, and so in those shells there really is very little difference between the two after all.

Ok - two exceptions. Now that I'm thinking about it, `ksh93` doesn't actually do a pipe at all for `|`, but rather handles the whole business w/ sockets - though it does do a deleted tmp file for `<<<*` as most others do. What's more, it only puts the separate sections of a pipeline in a *subshell environment* which is a sort of POSIX euphemism for *at least it acts like a subshell*, and so doesn't even do the forks.

The fact is that @PSkocik's benchmark *(which is very useful)* results here can vary widely for *many* reasons, and most of these are implementation dependent. For the here-document setup the biggest factors will be the target `${TMPDIR}` file-system type and current cache configuration/availability, and still moreso the amount of data to be written. For the pipe it will be the size of the shell process itself, because copies are made for the required forks. In this way `bash` is *terrible* at pipeline setup *(to include `$(`command`)` substitutions)* - because it is big and *very* slow, but with `ksh93` it makes hardly any difference at all.

Here's another little shell snippet to demonstrate how a shell splits off subshells for a pipeline:

```sh
pipe_who(){ echo "$$"; sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'; }
pipe_who
pipe_who | { pipe_who | cat /dev/fd/3 -; } 3<&0
```

---

```
32059  #bash's pid
32059  #sh's ppid
32059  #1st subshell's $$
32111  #1st subshell sh's ppid
32059  #2cd subshell's $$
32114  #2cd subshell sh's ppid
```

The difference between what a pipelined `pipe_who()` call reports and the report of one run in the current shell is due to a `(` subshell's `)` specified behavior of claiming the parent shell's pid in `$$` when it is expanded. Though `bash` subshells definitely are separate processes, the `$$` special shell parameter is not a reliable source of this information. Still, the subshell's child `sh` shell does not decline to accurately report its `$PPID`.

Comment: Very helpful. The in-kernel filesystem, is there a name for it ? does it mean it exists in the kernel space ?

Comment: @utlamn - actually, yes - simply [pipefs](http://www.linux.org/threads/pipefs-sockfs-debugfs-and-securityfs.5383/). It's all in-kernel - but *(aside from stuff like FUSE)* so is [*all* file i/o](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-3.html).

Answer (score 11):

There's no substitute for benchmarking:

```
pskocik@ProBook:~ 
$ time (for((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do cat<<< foo >/dev/null; done  )

real    0m2.080s
user    0m0.738s
sys 0m1.439s
pskocik@ProBook:~ 
$ time (for((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do echo foo |cat >/dev/null; done  )

real    0m4.432s
user    0m2.095s
sys 0m3.927s
$ time (for((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do cat <(echo foo) >/dev/null; done  )
real    0m3.380s
user    0m1.121s
sys 0m3.423s
```

And for a larger amount of data:

```
TENMEG=$(ruby -e 'puts "A"*(10*1024*1024)')
pskocik@ProBook:~ 
$ time (for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do echo "$TENMEG" |cat >/dev/null; done  )

real    0m42.327s
user    0m38.591s
sys 0m4.226s
pskocik@ProBook:~ 
$ time (for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do cat<<< "$TENMEG" >/dev/null; done  )

real    1m26.946s
user    1m23.116s
sys 0m3.681s
pskocik@ProBook:~ 

$ time (for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do cat <(echo "$TENMEG") >/dev/null; done  )

real    0m43.910s
user    0m40.178s
sys 0m4.119s
```

It would appear the pipe version has a larger setup cost but is in the end more efficient.

Comment: @mikeserv That was correct. I added a benchmark with a larger amount of data.

Comment: `echo foo >/dev/shm/1;cat /dev/shm/1 >/dev/null` seemed to be fast in both cases...

Comment: @user23013 That makes sense. I don't see why either `echo "$longstring"` or `<<<"$longstring"` would be tweaked for efficiency and with short strings, efficiency doesn't matter much anyway.

Comment: It is interesting that in my case (on Ubuntu 14.04, Intel quad core i7) `cat <(echo foo) >/dev/null` is faster than `echo foo | cat >/dev/null`.

Comment: @pabouk That is interesting. I added benchmarks for that too. For the small data version it wins against `|` which would indicate that it has a better setup cost, but for larger data it has pretty much the same profile like the regular `|` (it should be a pipe underneath in both cases). Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Interesting, but I am not sure if the overall interpretation is correct. We are executing one long "time" command, which will be processed once by the shell, so how can we guarantee that the heredoc is processed 100 times ? What if it was executed only once and reused 99 times ? One refinement would be "date ; for () ; do ; CMD ; done ; date". Another refinement would be to force CMD to be processed repeatedly, eg by making it a script or by involving randomness in the heredoc or using "eval".

Comment: @Prem - it isn't reused. The shell gets a unique name for the file each time. I guess one way to be sure is to use `ls` rather than `cat`, or both or something.

Comment: @Prem Yeah, that would be a better approach, but an even better one would be not to worry about this at all and use the right tool for the job. There's no reason to think heredocs would be performance-tuned.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed, the *pipe* creates a sub-process, while the *here string* does not. This may be important in some cases.

Compare these:

While:

```
grep $USER /etc/passwd | IFS=: read user x1 uid gid x2 home shell 
echo $user $uid $gid
```

displays nothing.

```
IFS=: read user x1 uid gid x2 home shell <<<$(grep $USER /etc/passwd)
echo $user $uid $gid
```

displays:

```
myuser 1000 1000
```